# Telegram webhook seems not to work with python APIs

Tags: webhooks, python-telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot with the help of [this API](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI), and I tried to implement it with webhook method, first I tried my bot with getUpdated method and it works like a charm, but when I updated it to webhook, it doesn't seem to work.

I implemented webhook with flask, exactly following [this example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_flask_echo_bot.py), except for the ssl certificate and IP, because I have an https domain, so instead of using IP and self signed certificate, I used my domain.

Then I tested my webhook with postman and sent requests with the data I got from api.telegram.org, and again it worked, but when I send a message to my bot in Telegram application, I get no message in the server, seems like telegram does not send the message as it is supposed to.

EDIT: Here I put my code for more clarification

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'mywebsite.com'
WEBHOOK_PORT = '8443'
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = '0.0.0.0'

WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/cert.pem"
WEBHOOK_PRIV_CERT = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem"

WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (TOKEN.get_token())

router = flask.Flask(__name__)

@router.route('/', methods=['GET', 'HEAD'])
def index():
    return 'OK'

@router.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.json
        print json_string["message"]["text"] # here I should get the text of message
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(3)

bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE+WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))

router.run(host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN, port=int(WEBHOOK_PORT), ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_PRIV_CERT), debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes i know, this doesn't answer your question, but anyway: Maybe you want to think about using [this python wrapper](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)? It supports the newest Telegram API (your wrapper doesn't) and there is a pretty good Telegram group where you get instant help and it is used more often then the wrapper you use. Just saying...

Comment: @Endogen I will try that wrapper too, thank you. and can you please give me the link of the telegram group you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

i think you sould use domain name or real IP address.

a little comment from your example link:

> In some VPS you may need to put here the IP addr

if you develop on localhost, you can use somesing like ngrok.io

Comment: well I have to say I'm sorry if I didn't mention, I'm developing my bot on my server from digitalocean, I have a VPS , and I have an HTTPS domain, so I send my requests to my domain and my flask server receives them

Comment: are you using a debug mode? try if not. url and port correctly?
also try to scan connections by `netstat` for example.

NOTE: are you use self-signed ssl?

Comment: I used digitalocean tutorial to create ssl certificate using letsEncrypt. I'm not sure which type it is,

Comment: yes url and port are set correctly, I have used nmap to check if ports are open, but I will try netstat for connections later, how am I supposed to run my bot in debug mode?

Comment: sorry for my inattention. debug mode are used on code example above.

`router.run(host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
                    port=int(WEBHOOK_PORT),
                    ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_PRIV_CERT),
                    debug=True)`

why did you make port as string, and then again as integer?

Comment: I used the port once to create the URL_BASE, but in router.run method, it needed port as an integer.

Comment: So, why do you make it as string?

`WEBHOOK_PORT = '8443'`

change it to `WEBHOOK_PORT = 8443` and in URL_BASE
`WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%d" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)`

or use the `format()` function. read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Yea thank you for that, I never learned python in a pythonic way, but I will :))

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of problems here.

1. Although this shouldn't be an issue, I have no clue as to why you'd use port number on a hostname. Why not simply use

```bash
WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s" % WEBHOOK_HOST
```

2. Your router endpoint should not have a token in it, your token should be a payload when you set your webhook. It should not be your origin. So,

```bash
@router.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
```

changes to

```bash
@router.route(WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + '/myWebhookEntry', methods=['POST'])
```

I'm not sure what your `bot.set_webhook` does, but the payload `url` should be `https://mywebsite.com/myWebhookEntry` and the POST call should be made to the URL `WEBHOOK_URL_PATH + '/setWebhook'` - I assume that's what your `bot.set_webhook` does but the url in the payload is definitely not what telegram would want.

3. Your certificate should be opened in bytes mode. `rb` and not `r`
   I was going bonkers for one full day trying to figure this out, making a POST call using python's `requests` module.

I started writing a POC for this exact purpose, using both `ngrok` and other tunneling alternatives and external SSL certificates.

You may as well take a look at the implementation, the solution has been tried and tested.

https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook

It's similar to what you do, implemented using multiple tunneling apps backed by `FastAPI` running on `uvicorn` server.

More references:
https://github.com/thevickypedia/telegram-webhook#references

You can always make a GET request or use a browser to hit `https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/getWebhookInfo` to see what's wrong with the webhook you set.